# Access error with administrator accounts

Tags: security, windows-7, domain

Problem: I have access denied on system files and folders, using accounts that are in the local\administrators group.

system is W7 Ultimate 64 bit that is joined to a domain.
the users that login to that machine, are added into the administrators group.

when logged in with such a user, I can't change/edit files within System folders (Windows/system e.g.)

If I login with the domain account (domain\administrator) - I can do everything.

iisreset - can't perform with a logged in account.  (only with the domain admin).

- I also tried to disconnect and reconnect to the domain - did not help.
- UAC is disabled

please advise.